# Sufficient statistics have the same joint distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

This is an example taken from Keener's Theoretical Statistics:

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent with common density: $f_{\theta}(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x} 1_{\{x \geq 0\}}$, $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ independent of $X$ and $Y$. Then one can consider $T = X + Y, \tilde X = UT, \tilde Y = (1-U)T$ and compute $\frac{p(x+y, \frac{x}{x+y})}{x+y} = \theta^2e^{-\theta(x+y)}1_{\{x \geq 0, y\geq 0\}}$. He then claims that $\tilde X$, $\tilde Y$ and $X$, $Y$ have the same joint density. I am not sure why. Shouldn' we be computing $p(x, y)$ instead?

Let me change the variable here: let $u = x + y, v = \frac{x}{x+y}$, then $x = uv$, $y = u  - uv$, then $p(u, v) = u \theta^2 e^{-\theta u}1_{\{u \geq 0, 1 \geq v \geq 0\}}$ which is not quite $f_{\theta}(x, y) = \theta e^{-\theta (x + y)}1_{\{x \geq 0, y \geq 0\}}$

Comment: Why couldn't it be? It is just in terms of different variables.

Comment: I see, and you are right, thank you for pointing that out. The book meant joint density rather than distribution. But I still do not see why they have the same joint density.

Comment: Have you considered what $p(x,y)$ actually is in the text? That seems to be the confusion.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you meant, but I changed the variables to be of the same form as $p_{\theta}$ in the problem description.

Comment: First consider joint density of $(U,T)$. Then transform $(U,T)\to (\tilde X,\tilde Y)$ to find joint density of $(\tilde X,\tilde Y)$.

Comment: But I have already given the formula in the text

Comment: The density $p$ of $(U,T)$ is known and you are to find the density of $(\tilde X,\tilde Y)$ from that. This should be straightforward. Why are you working backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He then claims that $\tilde{X},\tilde{Y} $ and $X,Y$ have the same joint density. I am not sure why

What your textbook is claiming is that the vector $(X,Y)$ has the same joint density as the vector $[UT;(1-U)T]$ where $T=X+Y$

Let's see why:

As per the property of exponential distribution $T=X+Y\sim Gamma(2;\theta)$ so

$$f_T(t)=\theta^2 t e^{-\theta t}\mathbb{1}_{t \geq0}$$

Thus

$$f_{UT}(u,t)=\theta^2 t e^{-\theta t}\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(u)\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(t)$$

1. Let's derive the joint density of $[UT;(1-U)T]$

$$\begin{cases}
ut=z \\ 
(1-u)t=v
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{cases}
u=\frac{z}{v+z} \\ 
t=v+z
\end{cases}
$$

Calulate the jaocobian that is

$$|J|=
    |det\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \\
    \frac{\partial t}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial t}{\partial z}  \\
    \end{bmatrix}|=|det \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{-z}{(v+z)^2} & \frac{v}{(v+z)^2} \\
    1 & 1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}|=\frac{1}{v+z}$$

and with fundamental transformation theorem you immediately get

$$f_{ZV}(z,v)=\theta^2(v+z)e^{-\theta(v+z)}\frac{1}{v+z}=\theta^2e^{-\theta(v+z)}\mathbb{1}_{z,v \geq 0}$$

2. It is self evident that the vector $(X,Y)$ with $X,Y$ iid $exp(\theta)$ has the following joint density

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\theta^2e^{-\theta(x+y)}\mathbb{1}_{x,y \geq 0}$$

...now the claim is proved.